# Unable to start the talker node even after sourcing the local_setup.bash file

Tags: ros, ros2, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS2 from the following link [Linux Development Setup](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup)

Even after sourcing the local_setup.bash file i am unable to run

> ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker

It says, ros2 : command not found.

As far as i know, this error comes only when you dont source the setup file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287518/unable-to-start-the-talker-node-even-after-sourcing-the-local_setup.bash-file/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-04-04**:
You might want to include the exact command you ran locally. Likely there is a difference to the instructions. You could also check your `PATH` environment variable to see if it contains a location of your workspace.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-04-07**:
@dirk thomas what do you mean by running the exact command locally ?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-04-27**:
The tutorial seems to work for others. So chances are high that either you slightly diverged from the instructions or something is different on your system. Only when you include complete information what exactly you did others can provide you with support. E.g. I asked about your `PATH` variable.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-05-02**:
@Dirk yes, i guess i was diverted from some instructions. I refixed it. We can close this issue.

**Comment by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) on 2018-05-02**:
The equivalent to "closing an issue" on ROS answers is to add your own answer to your question with what you changed, and then mark it as selected. Please do this so that people know you have found a solution to your initial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had messed up with the installation instructions, did it all again and works fine.

---

Originally posted by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) with karma: 667 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0